# Query on implementation of lock mechanism in java

Tags: java, jvm, mutex

As mentioned in Doug Lea's "Concurrent Programming in Java",

> Every instance of class Object (and its subclasses) possesses a lock that is obtained on entry to a synchronized method and automatically released upon exit.

Does JVM implement lock mechanism completely in user space?

or

Does JVM rely on OS kernel space system calls to implement lock? Please provide reference to the code that implements lock mechanism.

*Note: New to java multi-threading*

Comment: This is completely implementation independent. On linux, you can use `strace` to see any system calls. You'll most likely see [FUTEX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) calls.

Answer (score 2):

> Does JVM implement lock mechanism completely in user space?

Mostly, but not completely.

> Does JVM rely on OS kernel space system calls to implement lock?

It tries to handle the lock in user space but if the lock cannot be obtained for a while, it drops back to an OS lock.

The reference implementation is in the OpenJDK, which you free to download.

> New to java multi-threading

Getting buried/lost in the details might not be very helpful.

Comment: Reason to know about lock implementation, because using `synchronized` keyword at method level make sense to me where we are possessing intrinsic lock. But `synchronized(this){}` did not make sense to me. Why do we require something else(`this`) apart from possessing intrinsic lock to create critical section?

Comment: @overexchange it only makes sense to lock on an object shared between threads. Sometimes this shared object in one or both threads is one passed to it ie not `this` sometimes it doesn't make sense to lock a whole object and you want multiple seperately locks for protecting different sets of fields. Sometime you want to use the Class lock. Eg. `synchronised(MyClass.class)`

Comment: My question is, What does it mean to lock  `MyClass.class` or `this` or etc.. ? despite we have an intrinsic lock(which is a separate entity on its own that is maintained by JVM) that can be acquired/released? This is what we are doing when we say `synchronized` at method level. In block syntax, am not sure what we are doing, when we say `synchronized(this){}` or `synchronized(MyClass.class){}`, What are we actually locking here? Are we not acquiring that intrinsic lock in block syntax  case? Why do we need to rely on `this` or `MyClass.class` when we have intrinsic lock to acquire/release?

Comment: @overexchange when you acquire a lock is it the one embedded in an object. This is why you either have to specify an object to lock or for synchronised methods it implicitly locks the class object or instance.

Comment: OK. So, we lock the instance for synchronized methods. Then, How could another thread part of same object travel and come to that synchronized method and get blocked(spinlock(busywait)) at this synchronized method? I felt `locking an object` mean, no other activity within that multi-threaded object should happen.

Comment: "..is it the one embedded in an object" am not clear with this English.

Comment: @overexchange when you call an instance method you have to have a reference to that object to call the method. When a thread holds a lock no other thread can hold that lock. Another thread could be in another method which is not synchronised,  it could be in the same method for another instance, it could be wait ()ing in the same method for the same instance.